# How to get the value of class member?

Tags: perl, class

There is a following class:

```
package MyClass;

use strict;
use warnings;

sub new
{
    my $class = shift();
    my $self = {
        _class_member => "default"
};

    bless ($self, $class);
    return $self;
}
```

How can I set/get the value of the `_class_member`?

I tried the following code:

```
sub set_name
{
    my $self = shift();
    $self->_class_member = shift();
}
```

But I get the following error:

> Can't locate object method "_class_member" via package "MyClass" ...

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: FWIW, the name `_class_member` very strongly suggests to me a *class data member*, but of course you are actually implementing an *object data member* (or "attribute" in the parlance of [perlootut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlootut.html)).

Comment: "What am I doing wrong here?" You're not using Moose for your OO Perl programming :-)

Comment: @DaveCross I just got a task that regards to perl. It is not so easy after C or C++

Comment: @Alex: My point is that using Moose for you Perl OO would make your life much easier.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$self` is a *blessed* hash. Unless the you or the original author provided the method `_class_member`, there's no such method.

You can however, "reach in" the hash to access it:

```
 $self->{'_class_member'} = shift;
```

This is not a recommended practice for instance values because it's just as easy to type:

```
$self->{'_vlass_member'} = shift;
```

without a complaint. Hence the value of [accessors](http://perldesignpatterns.com/?AccessorPattern).